# how diff command behaves on if statement in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, conditional-statements

I have tried following code..

```
if diff f1.sh f2.sh; then
  echo Same
else
  echo Different
fi
```

Here.. In my case both **f1.sh** and **f2.sh** are different files.. 
So if statement prints **Different**(as expected) But how the condition becomes **false** and control changes to else statement... How it happening.. How condition becomes false..? How this diff commands behaves here.. Please explain the process in depth.. Thanks in advance (sorry if my english is too bad..)

Comment: look at the documentation of diff,  your distribution of choice should have it in teh /usr/share/docs or equal location   diff -a would do the thing  and IS script-able like so:  diff -a f1.sh f2.sh | cmd2 ....

Comment: I have looked at documentation of diff command and read about its exit status .. i got confused with exit status and boolean values.... so i am not clear with how it works specially for my above case.. That's why i am here.. this is a place to know na..!! but still getting negative votes for question :( ridiculus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. If you look at `diff` manual page, you'll see this statement:

> Exit status is 0 if inputs are the same, 1 if  different,  2  if
>   trouble.

Exit status `0` means `true` for the shell, so "Same" is displayed. In both other possible status, "Different" is displayed as anything non zero is `false`.

The `if` behavior is described in the shell manual page, here for example `bash`:

```
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
```

- ```
  The if list is executed. If its exit status is zero, the then list is
  executed.  Otherwise, each elif list is executed in turn, and if its exit 
  status is zero, the corresponding then list is executed and the command
  completes. Otherwise, the else list is executed, if present. The exit status
  is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero if no condition
  tested true.
  ```

Comment: Adding a bit to a thorough answer by @jllagre with a general tip that you may find useful. When things aren't working as expected, try to refactor your code to be as literal as possible. Meaning, instead of working towards the minimum number of characters to achieve the intended result, go the complete opposite direction. For example, you would likely have resolved this quickly had you rewritten the code like this: `diff f1.sh f2.sh >/dev/null 2>&1; ret=$?; if [ "$ret" == "0" ]; then <...stuff...>; elif [ "$ret" == "1" ]; then <...other-stuff...>; else  <...error handler type stuff...>; fi`

Comment: Also, the utility `cmp` might be a better choice for this use case; that way you don't get all the diff spam (can be reduced but not eliminated unless you dump to /dev/null). `cmp -s` outputs nothing to stdout. the result is in the return value, and uses the same 3 values as diff (0 is same, 1 diff, 2 is error).

Comment: Thanks to all .. I am new to shell script, so just got confused with exit status value and it evaluation to Boolean values.. Now i am clear .. Really thank you very much :)